# pt-pmp fails to run on percona 5.5 ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql-replication, percona, mysql5.5, debug, lag

**Command:**

```
[mysql] root:/mnt# pt-pmp --pid 16898
Wed Dec  7 18:41:51 UTC 2016

warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7fffd4126000
     18 libaio::??(libaio.so.1),::??,::??,::??,start_thread(libpthread.so.0),clone(libc.so.6),??
      6 pthread_cond_wait,one_thread_per_connection_end,do_handle_one_connection,handle_one_connection,start_thread(libpthread.so.0),clone(libc.so.6),??
      3 select(libc.so.6),::??,::??,start_thread(libpthread.so.0),clone(libc.so.6),??
      3 read(libpthread.so.0),::??,my_net_read,do_command,do_handle_one_connection,handle_one_connection,start_thread(libpthread.so.0),clone(libc.so.6),??
      3 pthread_cond_timedwait,::??,::??,start_thread(libpthread.so.0),clone(libc.so.6),??
      1 read(libpthread.so.0),vio_read_buff,::??,my_net_read,cli_safe_read,handle_slave_io,start_thread(libpthread.so.0),clone(libc.so.6),??
      1 pthread_cond_timedwait,MYSQL_BIN_LOG::wait_for_update_bin_log,mysql_binlog_send,dispatch_command,do_handle_one_connection,handle_one_connection,start_thread(libpthread.so.0),clone(libc.so.6),??
      1 poll(libc.so.6),handle_connections_sockets,mysqld_main,__libc_start_main(libc.so.6),_start
      1 fsync(libpthread.so.0),::??,::??,::??,::??,::??,::??,ha_commit_trans,trans_commit,Xid_log_event::do_apply_event,apply_event_and_update_pos,handle_slave_sql,start_thread(libpthread.so.0),clone(libc.so.6),??
      1 do_sigwait(libpthread.so.0),sigwait(libpthread.so.0),signal_hand,start_thread(libpthread.so.0),clone(libc.so.6),??
```

**Versions:**

```
[mysql] root:/mnt# pt-pmp --version
pt-pmp 2.2.19
[mysql] root:/mnt# gdb --version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>.
```

**Packages:**

```
[mysql] root:/mnt# dpkg --get-selections | grep -i "percona\|mysql"
libdbd-mysql-perl               install
libmysqlclient-dev              install
libmysqlclient18                install
libmysqlclient18-dev                install
libperconaserverclient18            install
mysqltuner                  install
percona-server-client-5.5           install
percona-server-common-5.5           install
percona-server-server-5.5           hold
percona-toolkit                 install
```

Comment: Please install the percona-server-5.5-dbg package and run pt-pmp again.

Comment: I would if I could upgrade my percona server but for some reason the last DevOps guy put a hold on any upgrades.... and that package wasn't installed so what to do? Can't find an old source of percona-server-5.5-dbg anywhere...

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 percona-server-5.5-dbg : Depends: percona-server-server-5.5 (= 1:5.5.53-rel38.5-1.precise) but 1:5.5.40-rel36.1-707.precise is to be installed

Comment: Try from the site: eg. `https://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-Server-5.5/Percona-Server-5.5.40-36.1/binary/debian/precise/x86_64/percona-server-5.5-dbg_5.5.40-rel36.1-707.precise_amd64.deb`

Comment: @jerichorivera got a 404...

Comment: I was able to download the file though, try again?

Comment: yes https://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-Server-5.5/

Comment: @jerichorivera got that package installed but still getting the same error